# Does Ubuntu 22.04.3 come with the Downfall patch pre-installed?

Tags: 22.04, security, intel-cpu

Does Ubuntu 22.04.3 Live CD/DVD image come with the patch for CVE-2022-40982 (i.e. with the latest intel-microcode package)?

I could not find this information in the [release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668) or the [change summary](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-point-release-changes/29835/4). So this means it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to determine the package version before install.

1. Go the the download page. Example for 22.04.3: https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/
2. Look for the `.manifest` file for your preferred .iso

   [image]
3. The `.manifest` file is just a text file. Open it. Or download it. Then Search for your package.

   [image]
4. [OPTIONAL for your mentioned CVE] Compare to the patched version number provided by the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-40982)

   [image]

In this example, the versions don't match: The `.manifest` contains an older version (20230214) than the patched version (20230808). Therefore that particular .iso does not have the patched version. This is understandable: The .iso was created on August 7, and the CVE tracker was updated on August 8. The patch missed the cutoff. Future respins of the installer will include newer packages.

Also, the very first time Ubuntu runs `apt upgrade` or Unattended Upgrades, including perhaps *during the install*, the patched version will be pulled in with other upgrades from the Ubuntu repositories. There's nothing special that users must do to get security patches immediately: A stock Ubuntu system checks for deb security updates twice daily and snap updates four times daily.

Comment: @szx the patch arrived a day after the respin was made. There's a whole paragraph about that in this answer.